# Force my footer on the bottom of the screen even if content is not big enough (without being sticky)

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I have a very simple question: When my content is not high enough to fill up the screen, the footer comes up and it looks a bit messy. You can see it here on a regular laptop monitor: http://www.dlgt.co

On that page, what would be the trick to force the footer to stay low ? I do not want it to be sticky though. I tried to set a min-height: 100% on the content container (#loading_effect) without success. Looks like a specific min-height in px works, but this is not going to work on all monitors.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `height: 100%` to the `html`, `body` and your main content. This moves the footer just outside of the screen. By adding a negative `margin-bottom` equal to the height of your footer to the main content you move the footer upward again. See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/wbony for an example

Edit: Ok, that didn't work completely. Retry using `min-height: 100%`, `box-sizing: border-box`  and a `padding-bottom` equal to the height of your footer. See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/jFgwd

Comment: After trying out a bit, looks like this causes issues if the content is bigger than the page, the footer gets above it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GetiI

Answer (score 0):

Or try using footer background to body. Before you use it, you should reorganize your structure that, to all sections must have 100% width with other backgrounds.

The solution is there: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kBLar

---

Or there - html:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    Content
  </div>
</article>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    &copy; Copyright 2014
  </div>
</footer>
```

and css:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  background:#222;
  color:#222;
}

header{
  background:#ccc;
}

article{
  background:#fff
}

footer{
  color:#ccc;
}

.container{
  max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: That's a solution, but I have some parts of the content that don't cover everything, which makes it a bit messy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was to have the footer be at the bottom of browser view ONLY IF the content was not long enough to fill up the browser window (non-sticky).

I was able to achieve by using the CSS function calc(). Which is now mostly supported.  You could use like:

```
<div class="container">CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

the css:

```
.container
{
    min-height: 70%;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 186px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 186px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 186px);
}
```

Change 186 to the size of your footer.